# Can static local variable be wrongly optimized?

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, local, compiler-optimization

```
std::uint64_t foo()
{
    static std::uint64_t var = 0u;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    std::uint64_t b;

    do
    {
        b = bar();
    }
    while (b <= var);

    var = b;

    return b;
}
```

Suppose we have two threads. Let the first thread read variable *var* to a register before calling lock() and the second thread read variable *var* to a register before calling lock(). Then the first thread changes *var* but the second thread does not see the change as it keeps the value in the register. Can this really bad situation happen?

I mean, usually only local variables are optimized that way: they are put to registers and later read from there rather than from main memory. And global variables should not be optimized that way as I understand. But what about static local variables?

Comment: "*...Can this really bad situation happen?..*" - Yes. The synchronization effects of a `std::mutex` is that `unlock()` *synchronizes-with* `lock()`. But you are talking about using the object before `lock()`  The only guarantee a mutex provides is that, modifications to `bar` by thread **A** within the `lock()`-`unlock()` sequence, will be visible to another thread, **B** after **B** `lock()`s the mutex.

Comment: You need to lock the resource BEFORE you use it, otherwise the other thread could lock it between the assignment and the lock, which leads to a race condition

Comment: @WhiZTiM Doesn't *C++11* guarantees thread-safe static?

Comment: @BiagioFesta, it does... The OP's question isn't about initialization of `bar`. It's about the use of `bar` before locking the mutex

Answer (score 0):

Static local variable has a global variable's lifetime, it just have a function scope. You must protect it the same way you'd do with a proper global variable (mutex/atomic).

**Note:** If you use **any kind** of variable in multiple threads (I mean when the threads use the **same** variable), then you must make it thread safe. Even, if it is a global variable. Even, if the variable is stored in memory. Storing a variable in memory doesn't make it thread safe. Thread safety is a concern not because some variables could be in registers. There could be a CPU, where different cores doesn't synchronize their caches automatically. So, for a variable, there could be multiple values in each core's cache.